# how to store more than 500 million of data and analyse the data in live?

Tags: python, mongodb

how to store more than 500 million of data and analyse the data in live? Can mongo db support these data for storage? can python analyse these data from mongo db?

I am planning to store the data in mongo DB. Can python read and analyse these data. I am worrying about the processing time. Is there any other efficient way to store and analyse the data?

Comment: I'm quite sure there's other ways too. Big data is quite popular. Also, please don't use Indian words like "crore", people won't understand them.

Comment: The answers to all the questions you actually asked are "yes". However, with my very basic knowledge, I believe postgresql would be better suited than mongodb.

Comment: NoSQL databases are well-suited scalable solutions for the live analysis of big data. In your case, yes MongoDB will be sufficient for your purpose and its very easy to interact with in Python. HBase is a great alternative too, and also has Python modules for it.